# How to define trigonometric results in certain form in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem here about trigonometric form in mathematica.

```
   Tabc2dqInv = {{Cos[\[Omega]t], -Sin[\[Omega]t], 
    1}, {Cos[\[Omega]t - 2/3 Pi], -Sin[\[Omega]t - 2/3 Pi], 
    1} , {Cos[\[Omega]t + 2/3 Pi], -Sin[\[Omega]t + 2/3 Pi], 1}};

    Print["dq->abc Transformation  Matrix is: ", Tabc2dqInv // MatrixForm]
```

The results shows:

[image]

The question is how I can constraint the results in "±2/3 Pi" rather that converted ""±1/6 Pi""?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use `HoldForm`

```
Tabc2dqInv = 
  HoldForm[{{Cos[\[Omega] t], -Sin[\[Omega] t], 
    1}, {Cos[\[Omega] t - 2/3 Pi], -Sin[\[Omega] t - 2/3 Pi], 
    1}, {Cos[\[Omega] t + 2/3 Pi], -Sin[\[Omega] t + 2/3 Pi], 1}}]

Print["dq->abc Transformation  Matrix is: ", Tabc2dqInv // MatrixForm]
```

[image]

Notice the form is preserved but `MatrixForm` didnt work because the expression now has head `HoldForm` not `Matrix`.  To fix that you could put each expression in `HoldForm` :

```
Tabc2dqInv = {{Cos[\[Omega] t], -Sin[\[Omega] t], 
   1}, {HoldForm[Cos[\[Omega] t - 2/3 Pi]], 
   HoldForm[-Sin[\[Omega] t - 2/3 Pi]], 
   1}, {HoldForm[Cos[\[Omega] t + 2/3 Pi]], 
   HoldForm[-Sin[\[Omega] t + 2/3 Pi]], 1}}

Print["dq->abc Transformation  Matrix is: ", 
 Tabc2dqInv // MatrixForm ]
```

[image]

Also be aware you'll need to release the hold to do most other things, eg:

```
ReleaseHold[Tabc2dqInv /. \[Omega] -> 0]
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2, 1}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2), 1}}

My general advice is to not get too uptight about the way mathematica decides to simplify things so long as its mathematically correct.

Comment: That was quick. Thanks for that. I can see lots of efforts to hold the form and only re-usable after release. I probably only keep it up when I need a presentation. Really appreciate the help.